# Problem when trying to instantiate a class dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to instantiate classes _0, _1, and _2 dynamically.

But in the `DynamicClass` class where I am trying to do this throws an error and I am not clear on how to solve it.

If I carry out the process in a static way, it is as follows:

return new _1 (). getProperty ()

I get the correct result,

but I need to do it dynamically

```js
abstract class Auto {
  abstract getProperty();
}

class _0 extends Auto {
  getProperty() {
    return 400;
  }
}
class _1 extends Auto {
  getProperty() {
    return 2000;
  }
}
class _2 extends Auto {
  getProperty() {
    return 100;
  }
}

class DynamicClass {
  select() {
    let random: any = "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    console.log(random);
    return new random().getProperty();
  }
}

console.log(new DynamicClass().select());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of classes beforehand, you can store them all in an array and access a random one each time.

```js
class _0  {
  getProperty() {
    return 400;
  }
}
class _1 {
  getProperty() {
    return 2000;
  }
}
class _2 {
  getProperty() {
    return 100;
  }
}
const classes = [_0,_1,_2];
class DynamicClass {
  select() {
    let random = Math.random() * classes.length | 0;
    return new classes[random]().getProperty();
  }
}
console.log(new DynamicClass().select());
```

You can also use the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function), which is more dynamic and is safe in this situation as you are not executing a user-provided string.

```js
class _0  {
  getProperty() {
    return 400;
  }
}
class _1 {
  getProperty() {
    return 2000;
  }
}
class _2 {
  getProperty() {
    return 100;
  }
}
class DynamicClass {
  select() {
    let random = "_" + (Math.random() * 3 | 0);
    const cls = Function('return ' + random)();
    return new cls().getProperty();
  }
}
console.log(new DynamicClass().select());
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use eval, it is safe to use it in this situation. However, I recommend you to read about it to know the risks of using it

```js
class _0 {
    getProperty() {
      return 400;
    }
  }
  class _1 {
    getProperty() {
      return 2000;
    }
  }
  class _2  {
    getProperty() {
      return 100;
    }
  }
  
  class DynamicClass {
    select() {
      let random = eval( "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3))
     return  new random().getProperty();
    }
  }
  
  console.log(new DynamicClass().select());
```

Answer (score 0):

If they’re global scope then: `new window[random]()`